# I have problem with CORS with SpringBoot and angular

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot, cors

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/public/auth/signup' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

this is the message i got when i try to interact with my backend application, i dont know why because I'm literally setting up everything that i know to resolve the CORS problem but nothing seems to work here is my settings.

```
`@Bean
    public DefaultSecurityFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource).and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/api/v1/public/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .apply(securityJwtConfigurer)
                .and()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .build();
    }
`
```

here is my bean of the cors

```
`
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig {
    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("http://localhost:4200"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("Authorization"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the **@CrossOrigin** annotaion on **top of the REST controller class**.

Note: This will enable you to communicate your BE from anywhere, if there is a precise domain that should be handled then you should try with this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/api/**")
            .allowedOrigins("http://somedomain.com")
            .allowedMethods("PUT", "DELETE", "GET");
    }
}
```

Comment: I heard using this configuration while using spring security will be neglected by the spring security, also I already tried it and nothing changes.

Comment: also even when i add the @CrossOrigin to the controller nothing changes i keep recieving the same message

Comment: delete the .cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource)